# How to specify files in gulp.config.js?

Tags: angularjs, gulp

I am using gulp to build my angular app, but I cant seem to get all the sourcefiles in a directory. The directory is called ./app/services so I defined this in the gulp.config.js:

```
  app_files: {
        // source, but NO specs
        js: ['app/*.js','app/services/**/*.js', '!src/**/*.spec.js'],
```

When I run 'gulp serve' I am getting an error that a service in the directory app/services cannot be found. When I move it to the app directory I dont get this message so it must be the config file which has an incorrect way of specifying the servicesfiles. How can I specify the configfile to include all the js files under the app/services directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following worked without any issues:

```
js: assetsFolder + "**/*.js",
```

Full Example including others:

```
var sources;

sources = {
  css: assetsFolder + "/stylesheets/**/*.less",
  coffee: {
    main: coffeeBaseFolder + "core/AppConfiguration.coffee",
    all: coffeeBaseFolder + '**/*.coffee',
    core: coffeeBaseFolder + 'core/*.coffee',
    controllers: coffeeBaseFolder + 'controllers/*.coffee',
    directives: coffeeBaseFolder + 'directives/*.coffee',
    filters: coffeeBaseFolder + 'filters/*.coffee',
    services: coffeeBaseFolder + 'services/*.coffee'
  },
  js: assetsFolder + "**/*.js",
  bower: ['bower.json', '.bowerrc'],
  bowerBase: "bower_components",
  images: assetsFolder + "images/**/*.*",
  sounds: assetsFolder + "sounds/**/*.*"
};
```

So I would try `"app/**/*.js"` in your case.

### Update

assetsFolder declaration is:

```
var assetsFolder = "src/main/assets/"
```

In your case either you don't need it or you could put `var assetsFolder="app/"`.

Comment: In your case either you don't need it or you could put `var assetsFolder="app/"`.